# jQuery Mobile retina icons not displaying

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

the retina icons are not displaying an the non-retina ones are too small. Im using 18x18 and 36x36 for *2.png. Any idea how to fix this?

```
.ui-icon-roto {
    background-image: url("imgs/roto_icon.png");
}
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .ui-icon-roto {
        background-image: url("imgs/roto_icon2.png");
        background-size: 36px 36px;
    }
}
```

Comment: @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){ //apply styles} does this work?

Comment: Also I doubt the size of pixels that you used see this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14

Comment: Same: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10902206/190695

Answer (score 1):

background-size should be 18x18

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .ui-icon-myapp-settings {
        background: url("settings@2x.png") no-repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
        background-size: 18px 18px;
}
}
```

Comment: retina size is 36x36 right for the actual file? and what should the non-retina file size be?

Comment: Yes, actual image's size should be 36x36 for retina and 18x18 for normal. Both should be specified with background-size 18x18 in CSS.